# How does the BWA-MEM algorithm assign its mapping qualities?

Tags: sequence-alignment, bwa, read-mapping

Is there any resource (paper, blogpost, Github gist, etc.) describing the BWA-MEM algorithm for assigning mapping qualities? I vaguely remember that I have somewhere seen a formula for SE reads, which looked like

$C * (s_1 - s_2) / s_1,$

where $s_1$ and $s_2$ denoted the alignment scores of two best alignments and `C` was some constant.

I believe that a reimplementation of this algorithm in some scripting language could be very useful for the bioinfo community. For instance, I sometimes test various mapping methods and some of them tend to find good alignments, but fail in assigning appropriate qualities. Therefore, I would like to re-assign all the mapping qualities in a SAM file with the BWA-MEM algorithm.

Btw. This algorithm must already have been implemented outside BWA, see the BWA-MEM paper:

> GEM does not compute mapping quality. Its
>   mapping quality is estimated with a BWA-like algorithm with suboptimal
>   alignments available.

Unfortunately, the [BWA-MEM paper repo](https://github.com/lh3/mem-paper/) contains only the resulting `.eval` files.

**Update:** The question is *not* about the algorithm for computing alignment scores. Mapping qualities and alignment scores are two different things:

- Alignment score quantifies the similarity between two sequences (e.g., a read and a reference sequence)
- Mapping quality (MAQ) quantifies the probability that a read is aligned to a wrong position.

Even alignments with high scores can have a very low mapping quality.

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t know the answer for BWA-MEM (since it differs from BWA!) but pretty much all other tools are described here: https://sequencing.qcfail.com/articles/mapq-values-are-really-useful-but-their-implementation-is-a-mess/

Comment: Maybe this page can help http://genome.sph.umich.edu/wiki/Mapping_Quality_Scores . Once you know the best and alternative positions where a read can align (or even the best and second best only?) it's not too difficult to implement I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there bwa-mem was published as a [preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.3997.pdf)

> BWA-MEM’s seed extension differs from the standard seed extension in two aspects. Firstly, suppose at a certain extension step we come to reference
>   position x with the best extension score achieved at query position y.
>
> ...
>
> Secondly, while extending a seed, BWA-MEM tries to keep track of the
>   best extension score reaching the end of the query sequence

And there is a description of the scoring algorithm directly in the source code of [bwa-mem](https://github.com/lh3/bwa/blob/master/bwamem.c) (lines 22 - 44), but maybe the only solution is really to go though the source code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the question is more about assigning mapping qualities. Even reads with a very high alignment score can have a mapping quality equal to zero.

Comment: Have you checked the source code? line 22 - 44.

Comment: @KamilSJaron Wow, that’s terribly hard to understand. The [actual code](https://github.com/lh3/bwa/blob/master/bwamem.c#L945-L969) unfortunately isn’t better. :-( At any rate, could you update your answer to include this more prominently?

Comment: @ KamilSJaron I did and it is still not completely clear for me even in the easier case of single-end reads.

Comment: Well I had no intention to actually explain the score (since I really do not know and the question explicitly asked about resources). I just knew about the preprint and I also got the idea to look at the source code, where I found those 22 lines of maths that seemed to explain the scoring.

Answer (score 1):

The MAPQ score appears to be calculated in the mem_approx_mapq_se function. I tried porting it to Python and inserting comments using ChatGPT 4, though I haven't tested it to ensure the output is identical to the original.

````
import math

# Constants
MEM_MAPQ_COEFFICIENT = 30.0
MEM_MAPQ_MAXIMUM = 60

def calculate_mapping_quality(alignment_options, alignment_region):
    # Determine the suboptimal alignment score, which is the second-best SW alignment score if available,
    # otherwise calculated from minimum seed length and match score.
    suboptimal_alignment_score = (alignment_region.suboptimal_score if alignment_region.suboptimal_score 
                                  else alignment_options.minimum_seed_length * alignment_options.match_score)

    # Update the suboptimal alignment score to the higher of the two: current suboptimal score or tandem hit score.
    suboptimal_alignment_score = (alignment_region.tandem_hit_score if alignment_region.tandem_hit_score > suboptimal_alignment_score 
                                  else suboptimal_alignment_score)

    # Early exit with zero mapping quality if the suboptimal score is greater than or equal to the alignment score.
    if suboptimal_alignment_score >= alignment_region.best_alignment_score:
        return 0

    # Calculate the maximum alignment length between the query and reference sequences.
    alignment_length = max(alignment_region.query_end - alignment_region.query_start, 
                           alignment_region.reference_end - alignment_region.reference_start)

    # Calculate the identity of the alignment.
    identity = (1.0 - (alignment_length * alignment_options.match_score - alignment_region.best_alignment_score) 
                / (alignment_options.match_score + alignment_options.mismatch_penalty) / alignment_length)

    # Compute the mapping quality based on the alignment score, identity, and other factors.
    if alignment_region.best_alignment_score == 0:
        mapping_quality = 0
    elif alignment_options.mapQ_coef_length > 0:
        # Adjust mapping quality based on alignment length and identity.
        length_factor = (1.0 if alignment_length < alignment_options.mapQ_coef_length 
                         else alignment_options.mapQ_coef_fac / math.log(alignment_length))
        length_factor *= identity * identity
        mapping_quality = int(6.02 * (alignment_region.best_alignment_score - suboptimal_alignment_score) 
                              / alignment_options.match_score * length_factor * length_factor + 0.499)
    else:
        # Use the constant MEM_MAPQ_COEFFICIENT for mapping quality calculation.
        mapping_quality = int(MEM_MAPQ_COEFFICIENT * (1.0 - suboptimal_alignment_score / alignment_region.best_alignment_score) 
                              * math.log(alignment_region.seed_coverage) + 0.499)
        mapping_quality = int(mapping_quality * identity * identity + 0.499) if identity < 0.95 else mapping_quality

    # Penalize the mapping quality for the presence of suboptimal hits.
    if alignment_region.suboptimal_hit_count > 0:
        mapping_quality -= int(4.343 * math.log(alignment_region.suboptimal_hit_count + 1) + 0.499)

    # Ensure the mapping quality does not exceed the maximum allowed value.
    mapping_quality = min(max(mapping_quality, 0), MEM_MAPQ_MAXIMUM)

    # Adjust the mapping quality based on the fraction of repetitive regions in the alignment.
    mapping_quality = int(mapping_quality * (1.0 - alignment_region.repetitive_region_fraction) + 0.499)

    # Return the final mapping quality value.
    return mapping_quality

```
````